# How to solve Error CS0229 Ambiguity between '_FormEvents_Event.Filter' and '_Form3.Filter'

Tags: c#, ms-access, interface

I am trying to call a Property called **Filter** that returns the string of the filter that is applied on a Table on my access application.

My library is:

```
using AccessApi = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
```

My code is:

```
AccessApi.Application ap = (AccessApi.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Access.Application");

string filter = ap.Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Filter;
```

But then Ambiguity Error occurs. I think I should overload somehow the Method I want to use but I don't know how.

Comment: Which line throws the CS0229?

Comment: string filter = ap.Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Filter;

Comment: Does renaming `string filter` to something else fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. My problem was caused by an auto-generated file which is used by Xamarin. The file implemented and declared the same variables as from my code.
Check you solution for auto-generated files.